# PHP image upload with watermark

Tags: php, image, upload, watermark

I have this code which uploads images with watermarks. The code works fine but the watermark function re-resizes all the images upload to small width and height. I want to retain the size after adding the watermark. I believe the problem is in function but I don't know how to fix it.

```
if(isset($_FILES)){
    $file = $_FILES['image'];
    $allowedExts = array('jpg','png','gif','jpeg');
    $uploadsDirectory = "imgupload/";
    $maxSize = 2000000;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($file['name']); $i++){
        $filetmpname = $file['tmp_name'][$i];       
        $errors = array();
        $filename = $file['name'][$i];
        $filetext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$filename)));
        $filesize = $file['size'][$i];
        $filetmpname = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

        if(in_array($filetext, $allowedExts) === FALSE){
            $errors[] = "Extension is not allowed"; 
        }

        if($filesize > $maxSize){
            $errors[] = "File Size must be less than {$maxSize} KB";
        }

        if(empty($errors)){   
            $random = rand(0,199);
            $destination = $file['name'][$i] = $uploadsDirectory. $random."_".date("d-m-Y") . "_" . $file['name'][$i];
            $upload_status = move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $destination);  

            if($upload_status){
                $new_name = $uploadsDirectory.$random."_".date("d-m-Y") . "_" .".jpg";
                if(watermark_image($destination, $new_name))
                    $demo_image = $new_name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Watermark Function:**

```
$image_path = "images/water.png"; 

function watermark_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name)
    {
        global $image_path;
        list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
        $width = $height = 300;    
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
        imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
        list($w_width, $w_height) = getimagesize($image_path);        
        $pos_x = $width - $w_width; 
        $pos_y = $height - $w_height;
        imagecopy($im, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $w_width, $w_height);
        imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 100);
        imagedestroy($im);
        unlink($oldimage_name);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the size of the existing image here:

```
list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
$width = $height = 300;
```

This is where it is making the different size image:

```
imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: this watermark functions I found it in other site and added to my code but the size image re-resize i don't how can fixed this problem

help me please @ryantxr

Comment: Check the PHP docs. You will see a complete description of the function and how it does image resizing.

Comment: resizing problem i fixed now but i have another problem if image png or gif he give me (is not a valid PNG file) or ( is not a valid JPG file) 
how can fixed this problem in  
` $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);`

Comment: Do not mutate the question. If the answer solved your question, accept the answer and open a new question.